# one apple overlay for multiple triggers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay

I like to open a login overlay with apple effect on a website.
There are different triggers to call the overlay.
Here is what I did:

HTML

```
<div id="top_nav">
    <a id="my_side" rel="#overlay" href="overlay_login.jsf"></a>
</div>          
<div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
        <a class="close"></a>
        <div class="content-wrap"></div>
</div>

<div class="call-button active" rel="#overlay" href="overlay_login.jsf">
    some text
    </span>
</div>
<div class="call-button active" rel="#overlay" href="overlay_login.jsf">
    some text
</div>                                  
<div class="call-button active" rel="#overlay" href="overlay_login.jsf">
    some text
</div>
<div class="call-button active" rel="#overlay" href="overlay_login.jsf">
    some text
</div>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
$('a[rel], div.call-button.active[rel]').overlay({
                    mask: {
                        color: '#ffffff',
                        loadSpeed: 200,
                        opacity: 0.5
                    },
                    effect: 'apple',
                    top: '15%',
                    onBeforeLoad: function() {
                                // grab wrapper element inside content
                                var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".content-wrap");

                                // load the page specified in the trigger
                                wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
                            },
                     closeOnClick: false,
                     load: false
                });
```

But this opens the overlay for the div tags only one time.

Any Ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When is your javascript code executed? I assume it's fired once by "document ready" event? Have you ensured that your html isn't re-rendered through ajax?